# Establishing Proper-Case filenames

Tags: excel, batch-file, windows-10, filenames

If I have a file named 'This Is A File.TXT', how can I rename it in Windows 10 using CMD so that the case changes?

I use Excel on a few-thousand files and generate a CMD script.
But the Case of the filename doesn't change.

I've even tried to rename it to 'SS This is a File.txt' (which works), but when I rename it from this to 'This is a File.txt', it reverts to the capitalised filename.

Comment: Open the explorer window and tap F5 (i.e. Refresh). You're dealing with a non-case-sensitive cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=C:\destdir"

SET "fromname=This Is A File.TXT"
SET "toname=This is a File.txt"

COPY NUL "%targetdir%\%fromname%"
DIR "%targetdir%\this*"

REN "%targetdir%\%fromname%" "%toname%"

DIR "%targetdir%\this*"

GOTO :EOF
```

produced

> Volume in drive C has no label.
>   Volume Serial Number is 830B-46FA
>
> Directory of C:\destdir
>
> 15/04/2017  12:45                 0 This Is A File.TXT
>                 1 File(s)              0 bytes
>                 0 Dir(s)  82,069,901,312 bytes free
>   Volume in drive C has no label.
>   Volume Serial Number is 830B-46FA
>
> Directory of C:\destdir
>
> 15/04/2017  12:45                 0 This is a File.txt
>                 1 File(s)              0 bytes
>                 0 Dir(s)  82,069,901,312 bytes free

for me, both on an NTFS and a USB drive, so it seems to work.